# Introductory linguistic theory books

Tags: syntax, semantics, grammar, theoretical-linguistics

I'm wondering where a good place (or good places) to start learning about linguistic (grammar, syntactic and semantic) theories would be.  I'm essentially a complete novice in this domain.  Any sort of resource - video, audio, websites, books, articles, etc. - would be great.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You can start from an introductory book, and then branch out. Any standard intro will do (Language Files, Linguistics for Everyone, etc. - whichever you can find at your local library).

Comment: See the suggestions [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3344/13238) and [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/20669/13238).